# Script to copy google form data to new tab

Tags: forms, google-sheets, scripting, copy, paste

I have no experience with scripts but found the following on here and it almost works for what I want.

```
  function onSubmit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const srcSheet = range.getSheet();
  const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Responses");
  const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn());
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, {contentOnly: true});
  } `
```

but I want the destination data to start in column J and not A

it works but copies the data to column A

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in which column you want to paste the data by changing the second parameter in `.getRange()` function. This line

```js
const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
```

would then look like this

```js
const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 12);
```

because columns also have numbers and L (the next free column) is equivalent to 12, since A is 1.

If you would like to use the letter of the column instead of a number, `.getRange()` function also supports so called A1 notation:

```js
const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("L" + (dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1));
```

To make the function work regardless of up to which column you have data entered you can use `.getLastColumn()` function, like this:

```js
const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, dstSheet.getLastColumn() + 1);
```

More details can be found in official [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

Comment: I have formulas in columns A-K but this script looks for the next blank row is there anyway to change this so it will ignore columns A-K please?

Comment: @MatthewBoucher I updated the answer, the last command would be the best if you don't always want to paste the data into column L.

Comment: getting there but it still pastes into the next empty row. If i have formulas in columns A to K and Rows 1 to 25 it will paste in row 26 can it be changed to only look for empty rows from column K onwards and ignore A-K rows? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @MatthewBoucher then just replace the first parameter with the number of the row you want to paste it in, or use A1 notation for the fixed cell, e.g. dstSheet.getRange("K1")

Comment: @MatthewBoucher if this answer helped you with your concern, please do upvote/accept it so that others will know the solution if they encounter the same problem. [meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)